# Why sometimes the in page css does not work correctly, like this case?

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the image and in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W5Yu4/ I have written the css style and the class in the HTML part but it does not work correctly, like it is not recognize the css class.

```
.model-landing-page .explore-wrapper {
width: 930px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
float: left;
border: solid 5px #96172e;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? If it's the `#96172e` border, then just remove `.model-landing-page `.

Answer (score 3):

Your styles are looking for an element with class `.explore-wrapper` wrapped in an element with class `.model-landing-page`. I do not see `.model-landing-page` in your HTML, try adding this class to your body.

Answer (score 2):

That CSS will only apply to something with class `explore-wrapper` which is contained in a `model-landing-page`. I don't see anything in the HTML with the `model-landing-page` class.

If you want to apply to either class, the rule should be:

```
.model-landing-page, .explore-wrapper {
  /* ... */
}
```

or just

```
.explore-wrapper {
  /* ... */
}
```

if you don't care about the outer class at all.

Answer (score 1):

maybe because your are using

```
.model-landing-page .explore-wrapper
```

while your html only shows

```
.explore-wrapper
```

putting those behind each other means that they are nested. so basically it's looking for .explore-wrapper inside .model-landing-page, which isn't there

Answer (score 0):

JsFiddle doesn't have a body in the HTML section so your `.error-page` and `.model-landing-page` classes are not present in you html. 
If you remove these classes everything works nicely : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W5Yu4/3/)